# set default dropdown values

Tags: php, forms

i have a form that submits 2 values to my database, when the form loads i check if there is already values in the database, i've been trying to use these values and set them as default on my dropdown boxes.  any help would be appreciated. thanks

```
<form method="post" action="add_res.php?id=<? echo $id;?>">
    <fieldset>
    <label>From</label>
    <select name='one' id='one'>
    <?
        for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++) // the interval for hours is '1'
            for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) // the interval for mins is '30'
                echo '<option>'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';
    ?>
    </select><br><br>
    <select name='two' id='two'>
    <?
        for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++)
            for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30)
                echo '<option>'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';
    ?>
    </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Restrict" class="btn_searchp"></a>
</form>
```

Comment: please tell us more information about `$hour` &  `$mins`. and why there are 2 `for` continuously?. what you want to do?

Comment: Am I the only one who hates the indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to combine the value and then compare with database value

```
<select name="one" id="one">
<?php for loop
$timeToDisplay = sprintf('%s:%s',str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT),
                                 str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT));
$selected = if($row['timeRow'] == $timeToDisplay ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
// let $row['timeRow'] is the value retrieve from database 
?>
   <option value="<?=php echo $timeToDisplay;?>" <?php echo $selected;?> >
     <?php echo $timeToDisplay?>
   </option>
</select>
```

**References :**

[`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

[`ternary operator`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: HTML attributes use double quotes, not single wuotes. Replace the `'`s with `\"`s. Single quotes may work in some browsers, but it is proper to use double quotes.

Comment: @C0deH4cker Single quotes have always worked for attributes in HTML, and always will. XML, however, will only accept double-quotes.

Comment: I stand corrected. Just searched it up to confirm and verified that single quotes _are_ legal in HTML, XHTML, and even XML. Good to know, sorry to be misleading.